# SQL Server - ListContains

Tags: sql

We have a table with a field which contains a comma-delimited list of integer values, as follows:

tblMedia

```
mediaID   categories
--------------------
1         1,2,3,4
```

I realize this probably isn't the best way, but it's what we're considering doing at this stage.

Given a random categoryID, how would you run a query that searched the categories column to see if the comma-delimited list contained that categoryID?

In pseudo-code:

SELECT * from tblMedia
where categories contains #arguments.categoryId#

Answer (score 0):

`LIKE` would probably do the trick for you:

```
SELECT * FROM tblMedia WHERE categories LIKE ('%2%')
```

Comment: LIKE would return a hit for category "22" if I passed CategoryID "2"

Comment: In that case, try using `LIKE ('%,2,%')`

Comment: There wouldn't necessarily be a comma at the front or end